# bash function execution from command line

Tags: bash, shell-script

I love to play with bash script a lot. But I want to enhance the way I use bash script. I have a script(`nepleaks.sh`) as below used during my programming,

```
~   1 clean(){                                                                                                                                                                  
~   2  lein clean                                                                                         
+   3  lein deps                                                                                          
+   4 }    
    5                                                                                                     
    6 runApp(){                                                                                           
    7   echo("[info] : make sure you've started neo4j.")                                                 
    8   #lein run -m nepleaks-engine.core  
    ............
   34         
   35 clean                                                                                              
   36 #runApp
```

When I need to `clean` my project, I have been commenting on `runApp` and vice-versa and then fire

```
$./nepleaks
```

Now, I want to amend this to something like

```
$ nepleaks clean or $ nepleaks runApp
```

I didn't like idea of sourcing `nepleaks.sh` and then call `clean` or `runApp`.

Here's one of the lovely thing I used https://github.com/cosmin/s3-bash/blob/master/s3-get, I am looking into but their script looked complex to me. 
They support something as below,

```
s3-get -k {accesskey} -s /{path}/{secretid} /{bucketname}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
case "$1" in
  (clean) 
    clean
    exit 1
    ;;
  (runApp)
    runApp
    exit 0
    ;;
  (*)
    echo "Usage: $0 {clean|runApp}"
    exit 2
    ;;
esac
```

Now you can do:

```
$ ./nepleaks clean # only run clean
$ ./nepleaks runApp # only runApp
```

Comment: Loads of Thanks for Cool script. What would be the case for 2 levels? I mean I sent `$1` and `$2` from terminal. I assume `case` inside `case`?

Comment: Yes, you can do nested `case`.

Comment: Ok, I will dry if I could do `./nepleaks runApp development` or `./nepleaks runApp production` etc. Anyways this is coolest script on earth.

Comment: @PrayagUpd: Do you try another `case` with `$2` in `runApp)`?

Comment: No. I tried `$2` before before `$1`, and is working but `*)` case is giving `./nepleaks.sh: line 56: syntax error near unexpected token )'
./nepleaks.sh: line 56: `*)'`. Hope I can fix it.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Nope, here's the gist : https://gist.github.com/iPrayag/ec0a468ad58b045b9b3d

Comment: @PrayagUpd: You missed an `;;` after nested `case`, line **17** in your gist.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat <./nepleaks.sh && chmod +x ./nepleaks 
> #!/usr/bin/sh
>
> clean() { ... ; }
> runApp() { ... ; }
> 
> ${clean+clean}
> ${runApp+runApp}

...

$ env - clean= ./nepleaks.sh
# ^runs only clean()^ #
```